# Visual Studio (2015) C Project dependency - LNK1561 entry point must be defined

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015

I have the following main program in a C project, which (the idea) uses a header and a utils file from **another** project in the **same** solution. The header file on consists of the declaration of the function found in the utils file (as you will see below)

**Main function:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header1C.h"
#include "utils_1C.c"
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    int num = 0, base = 0, rKey; 
    do {
        bool chk = false; //flag for while loop to check if base is correct
        printf("\nEnter number [Enter -1 to exit]: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &num); //number to be changed
        if (num != -1) {
            do {
                printf("Enter new base [2,4,8 or 16]: ");
                scanf_s("%d", &base); //new base [2,4,8,16]
             if ((base != 2) && (base != 4) && (base != 8) && (base != 16)){                  
                printf("Number must be either 2,4,8 or 16\n");
                }
                else chk = true; //set flag to true
            } while (chk == false);
            newBase(num, base); //calls newBase() with parameters num and base
        }
        rKey = getchar(); //getchar to clear char buffer
        if (num == -1)
            printf("\n[Press any key to exit]");
        rKey = getchar(); //readkey to exit programm on any key press
    } while (num != -1); //to be repeated until num entered by user is -1
return 0;
}
```

In a seperate project called Library:

**Header file header1C.h:**

```
char checkHex(int n);

void newBase(int n, int b);
```

**Utilities file utils_1C.c:**

```
#include "header1C.h"

char checkHex(int n) { //used by newBase() - converts given number to letters if larger than 9
    switch (n) {
    case 10: return 'A';  //return A if n = 10
    case 11: return 'B';  //return B if n = 11
    case 12: return 'C';  //return C if n = 12
    case 13: return 'D';  //return D if n = 13
    case 14: return 'E';  //return E if n = 14
    case 15: return 'F';  //return F if n = 15
    }
    return n; //return given number if < 10
}

void newBase(int n, int b) {

    static char newNum[50];       //array in which the number is stored (array of remainders)
    int i = 0;                    //counter
    do {                          //long division and gathering of remainder
        newNum[i] = checkHex(n % b);  //calling checkHex() to check number and conert to letter if needed
        n = n / b; //divide n by b
        i++; //counter + 1
    } while (n >= b); //loop stops when n is smaller than it's divider b
    newNum[i] = checkHex(n); //calling checkHex()

    printf("\nNumber in base %d: ", b); //flipped number - proper answer
    for (i; i >= 0; i--) { //loop stops when smaller than 0
        if ((newNum[i] >= 65) && (newNum[i] <= 70))  //check if newNum[i] is a letter [A-F]
            printf("%c", newNum[i]);  //output if letter
        else
            printf("%d", newNum[i]);  //output if number
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Error LNK1561 entry point must be
>   defined   Library C:\Users...\Assignments\Library\LINK   1

I have added the Library as a project dependency to the project which has the main function, and I have also played around with the

> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System ->
>   SubSystem

following other answers I found on Stack Overflow, but with no luck.

At this point I don't know what to do, and frankly I didn't think it was going to be this much of a problem (though I may be missing something?)

Apologies for the long question, and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `main()` returns `int` not `void`.

Comment: @alk I use void on purpose as I do not need it to return anything, though I do not believe it is the issue here.

Comment: You are compiling this using the C or the C++ compiler?

Comment: they are .c files so I guess with the C compiler, though Visual Studio supports both C and C++ so it's not a problem

Comment: @Logan IDE does not choose the compiler by a file name extension.

Comment: You need to explicitly switch to C mode in VC.

Comment: So as you seem to use C++, then the `void main()` definitely is the issue, as in C++ `int main()` and `void main()` is not the same.

Comment: My last comment does, doesn't it? @VictorPolevoy

Comment: @alk I changed the compiler setting to be compiled using C compiler (Config Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As) but the problem persists

Comment: You did a *full* rebuild?

Comment: Change it to `int main()` you lose nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling the code using C++ the linker expects an `int main()`.

As you define `main()` as returning `void` the linker does not find the program's entry point.

C++ does know about functions' return types, the functions' signatures, as opposed to C.

Comment: changed the main function to int returning 0, rebuilt whole solution from scratch - error persists

Comment: You did create a console-program-project and not to windows-program-project? @Logan

Comment: If doing C++ at least it should be `int main(void)` for example. @Logan